# CSS repeat image

Tags: html, css

How can I define `background-image` `repeat` with cap insets? I want the image to be repeated without border. Is it possible to repeat (tile) or stretch the middle in CSS?

[image: Resizable image with cap insets.]

The first (smaller) rounded rectangle is my PNG image. Red lines show cap insets I want to define. The latter (bigger) should be shown as result.

Comment: Actually, can you explain more. Unable to understand.

Comment: Sounds like a case for the border-image property.

Comment: I see you are looking for a HTML5/CSS3 solution. Why not, then, use `border-radius`, `background: 'gradient'` and `box-shadow`?

Comment: This does not work with background images. Tiling subrects of the background image is not possible without CSS hacks (some browsers do support them, most don't) or splitting the DOM element into nine parts. Either you use pure CSS3 as provided below (which I recommend), or you need to split your DOM element (possible with JS, but not recommended).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the CSS3 [border-image property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image).  It's designed for this sort of thing.

```
.box {
  border-image: url(my-image.gif) 20 20 20 20 repeat;
}
```

Interactive [demo here](http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/border-image-anim.html).

It's [supported on most non-IE browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image).

Comment: Excellent!!! One more thing to accept. How do I determine that it's a retina image and should be treated as with doubled px? Something like `image-resolution: 2dppx;`?

Comment: @user500 what was your solution for 2x images?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you could just solve this by using pure css3

```
.box {
 background: white;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```